# Click on link_to through javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I've been looking around for a way how to click on a link_to tag with javascript but it does not seem to work  for me.

I have a link_to that looks like following:

```
<%= link_to "", require_match_path(vacancy_id: vacancy.id, employee_id: current_employee.id), :id => vacancy.id %>
```

that I try to execute with some javascript

```
onMatch: function (item) {
        var myId = $("#matching > ul li:visible").last().attr("id");
        alert(myId)
        document.getElementById(myId).click();
        alert('done')
    },
```

The function gets called (I get the alerts) and it works if I put something static in there for example static id 1 in my link_to and document.getElementById(1).click();

But somehow when I try to get the data dynamically it doesnt seem the work. I can check with the alerts that it does indeed get the id correctly every time but when I pass it it does nothing.

Does anyone have an idea why? If you get the id dynamically is is passed like a string and do I need to change it, if so how could I check/fix this?

*In short: I have a function that executes a link_to correctly when I put static data in there. Once I get the data dynamically it doesn't work anymore. When I alert the ID that I am obtaining dynamically it does give the correct data. (My thought is that it is being passed in an unreadable format, no idea how I would go from here to change that.)*

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use jQuery !

```
=link_to "my link", require_match_path(vars), id: "my_link"
```

and then in your jquery you do the following:

```
$("#my_link").click(function() {
  // this is how to bind a click
  event.preventDefault(); //for not following the link target
});

$("#my_link").click(); //call the click
```